# Connection refused while connection elasticsearch in node

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using node version 0.10.33 and elasticsearch version 3.0.0 but i am not able to connect to elasticsearch.

```
http://localhost:9200/

  Elasticsearch ERROR: 2014-11-25T16:30:16Z
  Error: Request error, retrying -- connect ECONNREFUSED
      at Log.error (/Users/shank/Documents/MyUmpa/Server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:213:60)
      at checkRespForFailure (/Users/shank/Documents/MyUmpa/Server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:195:18)
      at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/Users/shank/Documents/MyUmpa/Server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:146:7)
      at ClientRequest.bound (/Users/shank/Documents/MyUmpa/Server/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1551:9)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
      at net.js:440:14
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)


Trace: elasticsearch cluster is down!
    at app.post.resturantController.ResturantInfo.name (/Users/shank/Documents/MyUmpa/Server/app.js:32:13)
    at respond (/Users/shank/Documents/MyUmpa/Server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:254:9)
    at sendReqWithConnection (/Users/shank/Documents/MyUmpa/Server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:174:7)
    at next (/Users/shank/Documents/MyUmpa/Server/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connection_pool.js:213:7)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Comment: There is no Elasticsearch version 3.0.0 and the error is pretty clear: "elasticsearch cluster is down!"

Answer (score 1):

Have you run elastic search server? If not then Download [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/) and unzip it into whatever directory you like. Next, open a terminal, cd to the directory you just unzipped, and run `bin/elasticsearch` (`bin/elasticsearch.bat` on Windows). After running elasticsearch server, run the node server!